# Cohomology of rationally equivalent cycles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. Let $Z_1, Z_2 \subset X$ be two rationally equivalent sub-varieties. Is it true that
$$
H^\bullet (X, \mathcal{O}_{Z_1}) \cong H^\bullet (X, \mathcal{O}_{Z_2})?
$$

Comment: A side note to my answer below - you might want to look up the theorem on "cohomology and base change", which does explain how $H^\bullet$ can vary in the fibers of a flat family.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I see what you mean. But I have next version of my question: is it true that $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathcal{O}_{Z_1}, \mathcal{O}_{Z_1}) \cong \operatorname{Ext}(\mathcal{O}_{Z_2}, \mathcal{O}_{Z_2})$?

Comment: No, surely not. Those Exts are related to the normal bundles of $Z_i$ in $X$, which need not be similar.

Comment: Yeah, the same counterexample works. For smooth curves $Z$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, we have $0 \to H^1(O_Z) \to Ext^1(O_Z,O_Z) \to H^0(N_Z) \to 0$, where $N_Z$ is the normal bundle. For the twisted cubic, this gives $Ext^1 = \mathbb{C}^{12}$, while for the elliptic curve it gives $\mathbb{C}^{13}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take a twisted cubic and an elliptic curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$. They have different $H^1$.

The condition of rational equivalence is much too weak to imply that sort of statement. Two equal-dimension projective varieties are rationally equivalent if and only if they have the same degree -- that's the only data remembered by the equivalence class when $X = \mathbb{P}^n$. Other $X$ will be more complicated, but the principle will be similar.

edit: They don't even need to have the same Euler characteristic, as the above example shows.

Comment: In a flat family of subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^n$ Hilbert polynomial is constant and therefore arithmetic genus is constant. Is not this a contradiction?

Comment: It's not a contradiction. There are no flat families linking the twisted cubic to the elliptic curve -- they are different K-classes even though they are the same cycle class. (A flat family can degenerate a twisted cubic to a plane cubic with embedded structure at the singular point; another flat family can convert this to the disjoint union of a point and a smooth elliptic curve. The cycle class "forgets" about this extra point, whereas the Hilbert polynomial and Euler characteristic do not.)